# How much did Native Americans steal from the Pilgrims?

Tags: native-americans, new-world, colony, colonial-america, 1600s

In *Of Plymouth Plantation*, William Bradford mentions one instance of Native Americans stealing Pilgrims' tools while they were eating dinner. The tools were later returned after negotiating with Samoset, a member of an Abenaki tribe, who could speak broken English.

Does anyone know any other instances of Native Americans stealing from the Pilgrims around 1620-1630?

I can find plenty of cases of the Pilgrims stealing from the Native Americans, but no more of the contrary.

Thanks!